# Unit testing, using Moq to verify the exception message

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

So, I have this test I have setup. It looks like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task LogErrorAndReturnSuccessIfNoLines()
{
    // Assemble
    const string orderNumber = "00000000";
    const string lineNumber = "001";
    var model = new OCS { Request = new strOCS { OrderLineID = $"{orderNumber}/{lineNumber}" } }; // NB: 12 characters means carpet
    var services = WmsContext.GivenServices();

    services.MockConfig.Setup(x => x.Live).Returns(false);
    services.MockOrderProvider.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(orderNumber, null, "Lines.Delivery")).Returns(Task.FromResult(services.WhenGetOrder()));

    var wmsProvider = services.WhenCreateWmsProvider();

    // Act
    var response = await wmsProvider.ReceiveOrderCompletedAsync(model);

    // Assert
    response.Should().Be("success");
    services.MockLogProvider.Verify(x => x.LogExceptionAsync(new Exception("Order doesn't exist on ERP"), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
}
```

This fails because of this line:

```
services.MockLogProvider.Verify(x => x.LogExceptionAsync(new Exception("Order doesn't exist on ERP"), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
```

If I change it to this:

```
services.MockLogProvider.Verify(x => x.LogExceptionAsync(It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
```

It passes. But I want to make sure that the message sent is exactly **Order doesn't exist on ERP**.
When it fails, it says this:

> Message: Moq.MockException : 
>   Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.LogExceptionAsync(System.Exception: Order doesn't exist on ERP, It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny>(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
>   No setups configured.

It also states that the performed invocations are:

> ILogProvider.LogTrace("OCS Received", ...

and

> ILogProvider.LogExceptionAsync(System.Exception: Order doesn't exist on ERP, ...

As you can see, the second one is the one I am after.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

---

Here is my **WmsContext** so you can see how the Mocks are created:

```
public class WmsContext
{
    public readonly Mock<ICormarConfig> MockConfig;
    public readonly Mock<IComplaintsProvider> MockComplaintsProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IDistributionProvider> MockDistributionProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IListItemProvider> MockListItemProvider;
    public readonly Mock<ILogProvider> MockLogProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IMessageProvider> MockMessageProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IOrderLineProvider> MockOrderLineProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IOrderProvider> MockOrderProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IStockProvider> MockStockProvider;
    public readonly Mock<IProofOfDeliveryService> MockProofOfDeliveryService;

    private readonly Lazy<IComplaintsProvider> _lazyComplaintsProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IDistributionProvider> _lazyDistributionProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IListItemProvider> _lazyListItemProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<ILogProvider> _lazyLogProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IMessageProvider> _lazyMessageProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IOrderLineProvider> _lazyOrderLineProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IOrderProvider> _lazyOrderProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IStockProvider> _lazyStockProvider;
    private readonly Lazy<IProofOfDeliveryService> _lazyProofOfDeliveryService;

    private WmsContext()
    {
        MockConfig = new Mock<ICormarConfig>();
        MockComplaintsProvider = new Mock<IComplaintsProvider>();
        MockDistributionProvider = new Mock<IDistributionProvider>();
        MockListItemProvider = new Mock<IListItemProvider>();
        MockLogProvider = new Mock<ILogProvider>();
        MockMessageProvider = new Mock<IMessageProvider>();
        MockOrderLineProvider = new Mock<IOrderLineProvider>();
        MockOrderProvider = new Mock<IOrderProvider>();
        MockStockProvider = new Mock<IStockProvider>();
        MockProofOfDeliveryService = new Mock<IProofOfDeliveryService>();

        _lazyComplaintsProvider = new Lazy<IComplaintsProvider>(() => MockComplaintsProvider.Object);
        _lazyDistributionProvider = new Lazy<IDistributionProvider>(() => MockDistributionProvider.Object);
        _lazyListItemProvider = new Lazy<IListItemProvider>(() => MockListItemProvider.Object);
        _lazyLogProvider = new Lazy<ILogProvider>(() => MockLogProvider.Object);
        _lazyMessageProvider = new Lazy<IMessageProvider>(() => MockMessageProvider.Object);
        _lazyOrderLineProvider = new Lazy<IOrderLineProvider>(() => MockOrderLineProvider.Object);
        _lazyOrderProvider = new Lazy<IOrderProvider>(() => MockOrderProvider.Object);
        _lazyStockProvider = new Lazy<IStockProvider>(() => MockStockProvider.Object);
        _lazyProofOfDeliveryService = new Lazy<IProofOfDeliveryService>(() => MockProofOfDeliveryService.Object);
    }

    public static WmsContext GivenServices() => new WmsContext();

    public IWmsProvider WhenCreateWmsProvider() =>
        new WmsProvider(
            MockConfig.Object, 
            _lazyDistributionProvider, 
            _lazyLogProvider, 
            _lazyComplaintsProvider, 
            _lazyStockProvider, 
            _lazyProofOfDeliveryService, 
            _lazyMessageProvider, 
            _lazyOrderProvider, 
            _lazyOrderLineProvider, 
            _lazyListItemProvider
            );

    public OrderViewModel WhenGetOrder(params string[] lineNumbers)
    {
        var lines = lineNumbers.Select(lineNumber => new OrderLineViewModel {Id = lineNumber}).ToList();

        return new OrderViewModel
        {
            Lines = lines
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't match because the two exceptions you compare aren't the same instance of Exception. Maybe `Verify(x => x.LogExceptionAsync(It.Is<Exception>(e => e.Message == "Order doesn't exist on ERP")...` works?

Comment: You are right; thank you for that :) if you put it as an Answer, I will mark it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't match because the two exceptions you compare aren't the same instance of Exception.

You can check if the message part of the Exception is what you want by passing in a lambda expression like this

```
services.MockLogProvider.Verify(x => x.LogExceptionAsync(
   It.Is<Exception>(e => e.Message == "Order doesn't exist on ERP"), 
   It.IsAny<string>(), 
   It.IsAny<string>(), 
   It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>(), 
   It.IsAny<string>(), 
   It.IsAny<string>(), 
   It.IsAny<int>()));
```